# SQL CLR return two new columns

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, sqlclr

I have a SQL CLR function which at the moment returns a string seperated by a comma.

How would I code the statement to return two new columns into my resultset.

For example

```
Select A, B, MyCLRFunction(X,Y) C From MyTable
```

Returns:-

```
One    Two    Three,Four
Five   Six    Seven,Eight
```

I would want it to return :-

```
One    Two    Three    Four
Five   Six    Seven    Eight
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to convert your CLR function from scalar- to table-valued to allow it to return more than one column.

see the [MSDN entry on CLR TVF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

It's not possible to provide a more detailed answer without more information in the question.

Comment: The OP would also need to switch from calling the function in the `SELECT` clause to using `CROSS APPLY` or similar (just in case this part wasn't obvious).